# Code chef :ODD , fastest way to calculate the nearest power of 2 for a given large number?

Tags: java, optimization

The link to the problem on codechef is:

http://www.codechef.com/problems/DCE05

The problem is:

The contestants have to stand in a line. They are given the numbers in the order in which they stand, starting from 1. The captain then removes all the contestants that are standing at an odd position.

Initially, standing people have numbers - 1,2,3,4,5...

After first pass, people left are - 2,4,...

After second pass - 4,....

And so on.

You want to board the ship as a crew member. Given the total number of applicants for a position, find the best place to stand in the line so that you are selected.

**Input**

First line contains the number of test cases t (t<=10^5). The next t lines contain integer n, the number of applicants for that case. (n<=10^9)

**Output**

Display t lines, each containing a single integer, the place where you would stand to win a place at TITANIC.

**Example**

**Input**:

2

5

12

**Output**:

4

8

I noticed a pattern:

```
For 1 : Output=1 (2^0)
For 2 : Output=2 (2^1)
For 3 : Output=2 (2^1)
For 4 : Output=4 (2^2)
For 5 : Output=4 (2^2)
For 6 : Output=4 (2^2)
For 7 : Output=4 (2^2)
For 8 : Output=8 (2^3) ans so on
```

So the answer every time is the nearest power of 2 which is <=number.

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException 
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int x=0;
        int output[]=new int[n];

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            output[i]=(int) Math.pow(2, Math.floor(Math.log(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()))/Math.log(2))); 
        }
        for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(output[i]);

        }
    }
}
```

**Approach 1:** I used Math.pow() to calculate powers of two in a loop until is becomes <= number , which I suppose was very inefficient.

**Approach 2:** I replaced Math.pow() with *2 in loop. (Still time exceeded)

**Approach 3:** I replaced multiplication by 2 with left shift in loop. (Still time exceeded)

**Approach 4:** I replaced loop with that log 2 logic, I found on stackverflow). (Still time exceeded)

Still it's showing time exceeded. 
What is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: @downvoter : Care to leave a comment?

Comment: Rounding down to the nearest power of two == extracting the highest set bit, see Integer.highestOneBit

Comment: @harold Still time limit exceeding :(

Comment: Well I have to blame something else for that, highestOneBit barely takes any time

Comment: @harold the code I am writing is: `for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
  {
   input=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
   System.out.println(Integer.highestOneBit(input));
  }`

Comment: @harold The code is being tested on 100000 test cases with numbers <=10000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be ensured that `Integer.highestOneBit` is the fastest part of your code. Even your original version was most probably way faster than parsing and formatting. I tried myself and succeeded with

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (sb.length() > 100000) {
        System.out.print(sb);
        sb.delete(0, sb.length());
    }

    final int x = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    final int y = Integer.highestOneBit(x);
    sb.append(y).append("\n");
}
System.out.print(sb);
```

The computation is trivial, so I guessed the problem was the output and added some buffering. There's probably a simpler way, but I don't care.

Another possibility is that the site works non-deterministically and I was just lucky.

Comment: Can you explain your code a bit more? The stop variable mainly : `final boolean stop = i == n;`

Comment: @Nivedita You continue as long as `i < n`, I stop whenever `i == n`. So we're looping exactly the same. The whole idea is to write into the `sb` instead of printing and printing only when the `sb` gets big or at the end. My implementation of the idea may look confusing to you; feel free to run your own (you can leave the loop as it was and add a `print` command after the loop and it'll be probably simpler and clearer than my code). +++ Update: I've just did it. +++ Btw., it's quite possible that the whole `if` can be dropped - I just wanted to make sure I don't run out of memory.